# filter existing array of object using simple map and filter es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Try to avoid using any library as I just need a simple script. I want to get non existing record from existing array.

`input = [{name: 'james'}, {name: 'jane'}]`

`existing = [{name: 'james'}]`

//do something

expected input to become
`[{name: 'jane'}]`

I tried this

```
let input = [{
      name: 'yahoo.com',
    },{
      name: 'google.my',
    }]

    existing = (existing || []).map(o => ({name: o.name})) //clean up data from backend [{name:'google.my'}]


    input = (input || []).map(o => o.name) //just in case input has more property in the future

    input = existing.filter(o => !o.name.includes(input))

    console.log(input)
```

Somehow I still don't get what I want (expect input to be `[{name: 'yahoo.com'}]`, what is missing? I couldn't spot it.

Comment: `{name: 'james', name: 'jane'}` is not a valid object

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @Eddie fixed the typo, thanks

Comment: @NinaScholz filter `input` base on `existing`, modified my question and added expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `find`

```js
let input = [{name: 'james'}, {name: 'jane'}];
let existing = [{name: 'james'}];

let result = input.filter(v => !existing.find(o => o.name == v.name));


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter with a lookup with `find`.

```js
var input = [{ name: 'james' }, { name: 'jane' }],
    existing = [{ name: 'james' }],
    result = input.filter(({ name }) => !existing.find(o => o.name === name));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) can be combined using a [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to detect missing elements between `arrays` of `objects` using `keys`.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const input = [{name: 'james'}, {name: 'jane'}]

// Existing.
const existing = [{name: 'james'}]

// Missing (B elements from A).
const missing = (A, B) => (s => A.filter(({name}) => !s.has(name)))(new Set(B.map(({name}) => name)))

// Output.
const output = missing(input, existing)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Comment: All good mate. `Array.prototype.find()` is definitely simpler to read. `Set.has()` is just more efficient at scale. See the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49528397/5566355) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of two [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The first one is looping through your `input` array, while the second one loops through your `existing` array to check if each `input` value is contained inside `existing`.

```js
let input = [{name: 'james'}, {name: 'jane'}];
let existing = [{name: 'james'}];

let res = input.filter(a => !existing.filter(b => b.name == a.name).length);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

First, don't reuse variable names, it's confusing (you have two separate things called `input`.

Second, don't do unnecessary loops. Do a filter right out of the gate and then map to get an array of names (or skip the map altogether if you don't really need it)

```
let input = [
    {
        name: 'yahoo.com'
    },
    {
      name: 'google.my'
    }
]

    //all names in existing that are also in input
    (existing || [])
         //I used some instead of includes
        .filter(o => !(input || []).some(i => i.name == o.name))
        .map(o => o.name);
```

[MDN Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Author wants retrieve alla names in input that are not in existing