# Sorting array of objects matching ids on a different set

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have an array of objects

```
array = [
    {id: 5, name: "Helen", age: 20}, 
    {id: 15, name: "Lucy", age: 30}, 
    {id:7, name: "Carlos", age: 1}
]
```

Then I have a similar array sorted differently

```
arraySorted = [        
    {id: 15, name: "Lucy", age: 2}, 
    {id: 5, name: "Lara", age: 11}, 
    {id:7, name: "Carlos", age: 10}
]
```

The ids of the objects on both arrays will always match, the rest of the properties may or may not.

What I need is sorting the array in the same `id` order as `arraySorted`.

(it can be also done on plain `JavaScript`, `lodash` is not necessary but maybe it will be useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `sort`, use `map`, `find` and `Object.assign` instead

```
arraySorted.map( s => Object.assign( s, array.find( t => t.id == s.id ) ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var array = [{
    id: 5,
    name: "Helen",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    name: "Lucy",
    age: 30
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Carlos",
    age: 1
  }
];
var arraySorted = [{
    id: 15,
    name: "Lucy",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Lara",
    age: 11
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Carlos",
    age: 10
  }
];
array = arraySorted.map(s => Object.assign(s, array.find(t => t.id == s.id)));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

See [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more info.

```js
// Raw.
const raw = [
    {id: 5, name: "Helen", age: 20}, 
    {id: 15, name: "Lucy", age: 30}, 
    {id:7, name: "Carlos", age: 1}
]

// Sorted.
const sorted = [        
    {id: 15, name: "Lucy", age: 2}, 
    {id: 5, name: "Lara", age: 11}, 
    {id:7, name: "Carlos", age: 10}
]

// Match.
const match = (raw, sorted) => (m => sorted.map(s => m.get(s.id)))(new Map(raw.map(r => [r.id, r])))

// Output.
const output = match(raw, sorted)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Comment: This is a superior solution compared to those using `find` (+1).

Comment: @trincot why is it superior

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) executes a blind search every time it is called. [`Map.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) retrieves `values` using set `keys`. These attributes heavily influence [`time complexity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

Comment: Other solutions use a main loop with `forEach` or `map` like here, but then they have an implicit *nested* loop inside it by calling `find` which will start searching the array from left to right, meaning `find` runs with a *O(n)* time complexity. The overall time complexity thus becomes *O(n²)*. Here, on the other hand there are three, not-nested loops (one loop runs *after* the other completes): two `Array#map` calls and an implicit iteration with the `new Map` call. `m.get` runs in constant time, so the overall time complexity is *O(n+n+n) = O(n)*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` to sort your array:

```js
let a1 = [{id: 5, name: "Helen", age: 20}, {id: 15, name: "Lucy", age: 30}, {id:7, name: "Carlos", age: 1}],
    a2 = [{id: 15, name: "Lucy", age: 2}, {id: 5, name: "Lara", age: 11}, {id:7, name: "Carlos", age: 10}];

let map = ((m) => (
             a2.forEach(({id}) => m.set(id, a1.find(o => o.id === id))), m
          ))(new Map());

let result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The new array can be obtained via [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const newArray = arraySorted.map(sortedItem => 
  array.find(item => item.id === sortedItem.id)
)

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map, and *avoid* using nested iteration methods (like `find`, which make the solution have a worse time complexity), assuming that indeed you have all the same id values in both arrays:

```js
const array = [{id: 5, name: "Helen", age: 20}, {id: 15, name: "Lucy", age: 30}, {id:7, name: "Carlos", age: 1}],
    arraySorted = [{id: 15, name: "Lucy", age: 2},{id: 5, name: "Lara", age: 11},{id:7, name: "Carlos", age: 10}]

const result = arraySorted.map((map => row => array[map.get(row.id)])
                               (new Map(array.map((row, i) => [row.id, i]))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, I have the same ids all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope this helps

```js
var array=[{id:5,name:"Helen",age:20},{id:15,name:"Lucy",age:30},{id:7,name:"Carlos",age:1}];

var arraySorted=[{id:15,name:"Lucy",age:2},{id:5,name:"Lara",age:11},{id:7,name:"Carlos",age:10}];

array = arraySorted.map(s => array.find(t => t.id == s.id));

console.log(array);
```